# Switch controls only half of rooms lights

Tags: wiring, switch, recessed-lighting

I have been working on updating my basement lighting to recessed LEDs. I have run into an issue where half work on the switch and the rest just stay on. (I am also pretty sure the ones that stay on also run power to my second floor outlets) I am trying to source the problem but having trouble doing so. I have attached a simple diagram. I believe the junction box that runs from the panel may be where the issue lays. Could use any advice on this one.
thanks

[image]

Update* Added photo of junction box
[image]

Update* New Solution worked out!
[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the junction box the switch connects to please?

Comment: You have not provided enough information for anyone to help you. - Read the other questions on this site about home wiring that have diagrams, to find out how to explain your problem.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Sure thing. I will definitely look around the site more to help clarify my situation. Is there some specific you feel I didn't describe enough?

Comment: Were the second floor outlets originally controlled by the switch?  Also, how difficult would it be to rerun some of the cables between boxes in the basement ceiling?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel no they weren't. the 2 junction boxes at the bottom of diagram were pull chain lights. not hard to rerun if needed.

Comment: @ThisGriff -- I take it the pullchain lights are the ones that stay on when you convert them to LED then?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Correct.

Comment: Why does your diagram show 2 cables coming from the service panel to this box?  I see 2 completely different groups of hot and neutral wires. Is that related to the 2 cables from the panel?  Can the second uninvolved circuit go into a different junction box?  (the box you have there is FAR, FAR too small for the 7 cables going into it, really I would task it for the smaller passthru, and get a 4-11/16" square box for all the other splices.)

Comment: @ThisGriff -- are the cables coming into the box 12AWG or 14AWG btw, and is that a KO visible at the top of the photo?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel 14/2 cable. and the KO on the side of the box (top to photo) is free yes.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica yes there are 2 cables running which is why I drew it in. (the wiring in this house is fucked). Thank you for the advice! I can get another box and sort this crap out better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I'd do.

[image]

There appear to be 2 circuits coming out of the service panel.  One of them seems to just "pass through" this box.   Identify the second circuit and remove it from this box altogether into its own box.

---

Note the receptacle box right below the "o" in Trial Version.  Run a new cable to the "J" box immediately below it.  Delete the cable marked with "X" between that box and the light it's fed from (that connection is fairly pointless, and it creates a loop, and loops are BAD).

At this point we have clean separation between the lamp circuit and the receptacle circuit.

---

That will leave 5 cables still in this box. For that you need 22.5 cubic inches for the wires + 4.5 cubic inches for the grounds + 2.25 cubic inches for the cable clamps.  That being 29.25 cubes, that octagon box at like 14 c.i. is laughably too small *even for 5 cables let alone 7*.  Even a 4x4 box (21 c.i.) is not enough by far.

I suppose you could use multiple octagon  box extension rings?   But Better off with either  a 4x4 box with 1 extension ring (another 21 c.i.) or a 4-11/16" (120mm) square box (42 c.i.) with no need for extensions.  These are American figures, but Canada code is basically the same thing metricized.

If you can find a 4x4 box with integral cable clamps, that is fine.  Probably won't find a 4-11/16" (120mm) box like that, but you can just use cable clamps designed to screw into "knockouts".  Use all knockouts on the base box, do not use any knockouts on the extension box.

So use that for the 5-cable box and the original box for the 2-cable splice box.

At that point you'll have 5 cables left:

- 1 supply cable
- 1 switch loop (glad you're in CA or you'd have to re-run that with /3 cable)
- 3 runs to lamp strings

For ease of marking, we're going to re-define "always-hot" wire as blue and "switched-hot" wire as black.

- Supply black gets re-marked blue (always-hot)
- White wire in switch loop gets re-marked blue

Now join all blues.
Join all whites.
Join all blacks (switched-hot here).

Comment: Thanks for this! I will get what I need tomorrow.

Comment: @ThisGriff Well, you did most of the heavy lifting by color-coding everything so nice :)

Comment: Haha thanks! If I didn't start to colour code this house would have driven me even more crazy :D

Comment: Thanks for the help! All is working. However the one line that was "passing though" that crowded junction box was actually the line to my dishwasher in kitchen, which is not properly labeled and in its own box. So to fix the outlet light issue I added the bottom set of lights to the the others and ran power to the outlets on their own. cleaned up the first box like up mention in a new 4-11/16" box and all labeled up!